# Search another app in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Pretty self-explanatory. Is this possible? I'd like to automatically use the search function in another app - say, ColorDict - from mine. So, for example, if somebody enters the string "xyz", it should open ColorDict, searching for the string "xyz".

I figured it has something to do with INTENT_SEARCH, but I can't for the life of me figure out what. I'd appreciate any help. :)

Comment: you are confusing. about which search function you are speaking ?

Comment: The hypothetical inbuilt search function in the target application. Assuming it exists.